# nginx: invalid option: "nginx-debug" in docker

Tags: docker, nginx

I want to enable debug in my nginx and I am getting `nginx: invalid option: "nginx-debug"` error. Please help me to fix this error. Below is my Docker file for reference. When I remove nginx-debug everything works fine.

```
FROM nginx:1.25-alpine
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /nginx.conf.template
CMD ["/bin/sh" , "-c" , "envsubst '$APP_HOST' < /nginx.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx nginx-debug -g 'daemon off;'"]
EXPOSE 80
```